# Not able to query to two different cassandra cluster in same app

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I created cassandra session for two separate cluster using datastax driver in one java application. Session got created successfully however when I query, query on first cluster (pick any one) get executed successfully however query on second cluster always fails with below error. Please help me resolving this issue.

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Tried to execute unknown prepared query 0x5f318143588bfa8c5deb2245224cf2da

**Note: I have requirement to connect to two separate cluster in same app. Please don't ask why.**

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace, it is likely that you are trying to execute on session 1 a `BoundStatement` that belongs to session 2. `PreparedStatement` and `BoundStatement` instances can only be used with the session that created them. 
In your situation, you will need to prepare each statement you plan to use in your application *on both sessions*.